# How to use Docker to convert Rmarkdown to HTML?

Tags: r, docker, r-markdown

How to convert the following `test.rmd` using Docker to a give an output as an `.html` document?

I am not able to find a short and simple example out here without requiring RStudio to be setup in a docker container.

**test.rmd**

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "John Doe"
date: "5/15/2019"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: lumen
---

## R Markdown

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

## Scatter Plot

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()
``
````

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an answer for you (with two corrections/changes) based on a [Rocker container I made for Rmd](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker/tree/master/r-rmd) and which I had locally.  It is fairly minimal: R plus `rmarkdown` plus a full LaTeX stack (that aspect mattered to me, it may not to you) and little else, but `ggplot2`. You can download it with a standard `docker pull rocker/r-rmd` from the [Rocker account at the Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/).

I had to make two changes to your Rmd file. First, I added the missing third backtick on the last line.  Then, I also had to remove the lumen theme.  That may come from another package -- I do not recall.  After that, the following command does the trick (and your example is save as `file.Rmd`):

```sh
docker run --rm -ti -v${PWD}:/work -w/work \
    rocker/r-rmd Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd")'
```

#### Output log on my box

```sh
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/56157292(master)$ docker run --rm -ti -v${PWD}:/work -w/work rocker/r-rmd Rscript -e 'rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd")'


processing file: file.Rmd
  |................................                                 |  50%
  ordinary text without R code

  |.................................................................| 100%
label: unnamed-chunk-1

output file: file.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS file.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output file.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --standalone --section-divs --template /usr/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/h/default.html --no-highlight --variable highlightjs=1 --variable 'theme:bootstrap' --include-in-header /tmp/Rtmp6683qu/rmarkdown-str1417442cc.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'

Output created: file.html
edd@rob:~/git/stackoverflow/56157292(master)$
```

#### Rendered Output

[image]

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add but I am using Windows 10. How do I translate the `${PWD}` and get the `.html` file as output in the same folder?

Comment: Ah, yes, ${PWD} is a Unix shell shorthand for 'print current directory.  Just replace `${PWD}` with the full path of your folder, say `C:/users/myname/documents` and keep the `:/work` as that is where Docker sees it.  Else follow standard 'Docker on Windows and directory sharing' tutorials which may explain the same in more words.

Comment: Thank you. I am not able to test this right now, because of a port issue but I will mark this as resolved. I will have a question on how to bulk run `.rmd` files on a scheduler which I will ask on github. Thank you.

Comment: You can just hand off to a script that loops over files.  Really a new question...

Comment: Fantastic answer @DirkEddelbuettel